# has_many as: source relationship producing unexpected SQL (Railcast #364)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I am implementing the Active Record Reputation System as described in [Railscast 364](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system?view=asciicast).

I've got most of it working, including the voting and the totaling (per user and per post).

I have a problem when trying to hide the voting options when a user has already voted.  The Railscast uses a function `voted_for?` to do this hiding.  I've looked around for the answer but either no one else has had this problem (unlikely) or I can't transpose their issue back to mine (likely).

My adapted code, with 4 lines I run separately, reads:

```
# snippet of User.rb:

has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source
has_reputation :votes, source: {reputation: :votes, of: :microposts}, aggregated_by: :sum

def voted_for?(micropost)
  evaluations.where(target_type: micropost.class, target_id: micropost.id).present? #1.
  evaluations.exists?(target_type: micropost.class, target_id: micropost.id)        #2.
  true                                                                              #3.
  evaluations.exists?(target_type: "Micropost", target_id: 1)                       #4.
end
```

Explanation of lines marked 1-4:

1. is adapted from the Railscast and doesn't hide the voting options
2. is apparently more efficient but produces the same problem
3. proves the rest of the code works: ALL the links hide when this option runs
4. produces this SQL (as taken from the `development.log`):

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rs_evaluations"
   WHERE "rs_evaluations"."target_id" = 1           # this should be "source_id"
   AND "rs_evaluations"."target_type" = 'User'      # this should be "source_type"
   AND "rs_evaluations"."target_type" = 'Micropost' # correct
   AND "rs_evaluations"."target_id" = 302           # correct
   ```

So I've found the problem.  If I run the SQL with the correct column names, it works as expected.

How do I fix this in my rails code?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is your SQL that is coming up incorrect, double check that your models have all the correct associations in them.  Make sure User `has_many :microposts` and make sure Micropost is similar to the following.

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
end
```

Also, double check that you have migrated your database and that it has all the correct columns you need for those associations.

Comment: Yeah my User `has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy`.  Micropost is similar to above.  I ran `rake db:migrate`, `rake db:migrate`, `rake db:migrate` but the problem is the same

Comment: Hmmmm, and I'm assuming you are using Rails 3.2.6 or above since that is what was used in the Railscast and you ran the proper terminal commands `rails g reputation_system` and clearly you migrated :)...The seems like it should be in the associations somewhere since that is what ActiveRecord uses to create the SQL query.  Unfortunately, Im not super familiar with the gem activerecord-reputation-system so this is my best guess based on your info. Good Luck!

Comment: I meant to say I ran `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:populate db:test:prepare` above

Comment: I was using Rails 3.2.12 but went to 3.2.6 to see if it made a difference (it didn't).  I agree with your diagnosis, it seems like the associations.  Thanks for your help.